# Publish stucks in visual studio while publishing it on azure

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am not able to publish the API associated with Web jobs to azure API app. It got stuck with no exception after publish started. Attached herewith the screenshot for your reference.

I tried publishing blank API app on the same location. At that time, I haven't got any issue related to publish.

Also, in some cases if I change the project location/computer it gets successfully publish on first time. But on subsequent publish, it ends with same result.

Please let me know if anything else is required. Here is a screenshot:

[image]